# How many different sums: probability

Tags: probability, combinations

I have six $1$ dollar bills, two $5$ dollar bills, and three $10$ dollar bills. How many different sums of money are possible?

So far I am thinking $3c$$_1$ + $3c$$_2$ + $3$$c_3$ would be the case if I had 1 of each. The addition of more is what is throwing me off.

Comment: Pst: They are just asking for how many sums it is possible to make, not how many different arrangements of bills make them.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Certainly you can make \$0 and \$46.  Can you make every quantity in between?

With four \$1s, a \$5, and all three \$10s, you can make every quantity from \$1 to \$39.  (Can you explain this?)

Then can you demonstrate how to fill the gap of \$40 through \$45?